# absolute addressing - relocations

Tags: iphone

so I upgrade to Snow Leopard and XCode 3.2.3 / SDK4

now my project won't compile:

ld: absolute addressing (perhaps -mdynamic-no-pic) used in -[MyAppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] from /Users/ade/Documents/XCodeprojects/MyApp/build/MyApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Objects-normal/armv6/MyAppDelegate.o not allowed in slidable image. Use '-read_only_relocs suppress' to enable text relocs

Command /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2 failed with exit code 1

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated...

ade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I need

[GCC_LINK_WITH_DYNAMIC_LIBRARIES, -static]

checked.

ade.